# cron job debain amazon ec2 instatance error

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, cron, phpunit, npm

cron job debain amazon ec2 instatance error

my cron job runs a script 
which gives me an error as

```
   phpunit: not found
   npm: not found
```

where as they are installed already in the system

```
   root@:~# phpunit --version
   PHPUnit 4.0.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

   root@:~# npm --version
   1.3.17
```

but if i try to run the script normal like

```
 sh /pth/to/file.sh
```

i runs PERFECTLY OKK

but in CRON JOB IT GIVES ME AN ERROR

Comment: I guess you need to indicate the full path of both `phpunit` and `npm` in your script. Also, are you executing your cron with root user?

Comment: thanku for replay
kk i will try it

Comment: how can i get its full path

Comment: i have installed it using composer

Comment: Do `which phpunit`, `which npm`.

Comment: thanku very much @fedorqui

Comment: Nice to read that! I post it as an answer so that it is clear that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in comments, it was a matter to use the full path of your script:

You were getting

> phpunit: not found
>     npm: not found

Because you were probably calling the functions like

```
phpunit blabla
```

As cronjob does have a reduced environment, you need normally need to specify the whole paths. To get them, do `which phpunit`. And use the output accordingly:

```
/bin/phpunit blabla
```